# Purpose and/or Description for "Is Controlled by System" Field on User Record Requested

Tags: fields, user-record

I was working on a Validation Rule today for User Records, and notice a field on the User Record **"Is Controlled by System",**.  This looks promising and useful, however, I can't seem to find anything about this field and it's purpose on help & training, the developer site, or even google. I'm assuming this is user error, but..

Does anyone know, what the intended purpose of this field is and what "Controlled by System" actually means?
[image: User Field, "Is Controlled by System", Type: "Checkbox", API Name: IsSystemControlled]
**Field Details**
Object:  User
Field Label:  Is Controlled  by System
API name: IsSystemControlled
Is Custom:  FALSE
Type: Checkbox

Comment: Is this a Summer 15 org by chance? For what it is work I can't see the User.IsSystemControlled field using v33.0 of the API. Maybe a particular feature needs to be enabled in the org.

Comment: I am on Summer 15 in the Sandbox I found this in, but I checked my Spring 15 production org, and the field is available as well.

Comment: I've checked several orgs that I have access to and can't see it on User. It is probably something specific to a feature that is enabled in your org. Which users have `IsSystemControlled = true`? That might provide some clues.